# Is there anything inherently wrong to use the Black-Scholes-Merton model to simulate BTC pricing rather than only using it for Options pricing?

Tags: forecasting, simulation, monte-carlo

My understanding of the Black Scholes model is that it can be used to simulate options pricing for stocks in traditional financial markets. But this [article](https://bgeometrics.com/2022/12/04/simulation-of-the-bitcoin-price-with-the-monte-carlo-method/) uses the model to forecast/simulate bitcoin (BTC) price directly. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with using it to simulate BTC price directly? If so, what other methods are more suitable for this purpose?

Comment: *Options pricing* refers to a particular application involving the computation of expectations of certain functionals of stochastic processes. The geometric brownian motion is just one of (infinitely) many stochastic processes, and it has no intrinsic link to options pricing whatsoever (and it does not originate from this literature at all). In fact, the kind of simulation undertaken here is very different from the kind that you would perform in an options pricing context because it is done under the physical measure (not a "risk-neutral" or "equivalent martingale measure").

Answer (score 1):

Black and Scholes model (BS) start from the hypothesis of geometric brownian motion (GBM) for stock price dynamics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion). In the article you linked Monte Carlo (MC) procedure is used for simulate GBM trajectories I suppose, no BS because It is for option pricing. Moreover, in the extent GBM is good for BTC price dynamics, BS is good for option written on BTC. In any case MC is a standard method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) for prices simulation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "no BS because It is for option pricing"? The URL mentioned "This is the formula of the Black-Scholes-Merton (1973 stochastic differential equation (SDE) economic model that we will use to generate the simulation." And in the implementation it set T = 1 (# Maturity. Option expiration date. We set it to 1) and T = 1 (# Maturity. Option expiration date. We set it to 1) which I believe are part of the B-S model

Comment: Several objects are involved in the “BS model” latu sensu intended. However, as I tried to summarize in my reply, BS model boil down in a formula for option pricing, the famous BS formula. This cannot be used for simulate nothing, and this fact reply to your ask It seems me. Usually prices is what we need to simulate, then we need of a stochastic process hypothesis about It and related simulation algorithm like those of MC family. Indeed in the graph plotted we read “Bitcoin simulation [based on] Monte Carlo …”.

Comment: The phrase you refers on seems me unfortunate. The mentioned SDE represent the GBM dynamic and is the rule for simulation, however it is involved in BS model but is not the formula of BS. It's like confusing the hammer with the nail.